# ¿Por qué tengo un error en la sintaxis de mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Aparece el siguiente error cuando trato de insertar un campo nuevo a la base de datos. Estos mensajes aparecen como errores de excepción:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOMBRE=,FECHAACTUAL=2018-02-07,HORA=03:58' at line 1

```
 String h = " INSERT INTO datosventas SET RUT="+datosFinales1[0]+",NOMBRE="+datosFinales1[1]+",FECHAACTUAL="+fechaActual+",HORA="+hora;
 conexion.darStatement().executeUpdate(h);
```

Donde `datosFinales1` es un arreglo de strings que tiene en ciertas posiciones valor `null`. Esto traté de corregirlo con el siguiente ciclo `for`:

```
for(int i=0;i<datosFinales1.length;i++){
        if(datosFinales1[i]==null){
            datosFinales1[i]=" ";
        }
}
```

Comment: Las cadenas de texto deben estar entrecomilladas y según tu código no lo están. Más aún, debes usar consultas preparadas para evitar que la consulta SQL sufra agujeros de seguridad como inyección SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes tanto un problema con la sintaxis SQL de un `INSERT` como problemas a la hora de entrecomillar los datos en la consulta:

```
INSERT INTO <tabla> (campo1, campo2, ...) VALUES (valor1, valor2, ...)
```

Las cadenas de caracteres deben estar entre comillas:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo) VALUES ('Valor de texto')
```

Para agregar cadenas correctamente entrecomilladas a una consulta SQL te recomiendo usar [consultas preparadas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
/* La conexión está definida en "conexion" según el código proporcionado */
PreparedStatement insertarStmt = null;
String insertString = "INSERT INTO datosventas " +
    " (RUT, NOMBRE, FECHAACTUAL, HORA) " +
    " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
try {
  conexion.setAutoCommit(false);
  insertarStmt = conexion.prepareStatement(insertString);
  /* Asignamos las variables a cada "?" de la consulta SQL */
  insertarStmt.setString(1, datosFinales1[0]);
  insertarStmt.setString(2, datosFinales1[1]);
  insertarStmt.setString(3, fechaActual);
  insertarStmt.setString(4, hora);
  /* Aunque se llame "executeUpdate" no implica que se use únicamente para
    actualizaciones es simplemente para indicar una consulta SQL que no
    tiene datos de retorno */
  insertarStmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  /* ... */
} finally {
  /* ... */
}
```

En caso contrario tu código sufrirá de un agujero de seguridad llamado ["inyección SQL"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Puedes ver el alcance del riesgo que supone no hacerlo bien en [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY?t=15m52s).

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono

Answer (score 2):

Estas mezclando "INSERT INTO" con "UPDATE FROM SET".
la forma correcta de un Insert es:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1,campo2,...) 
VALUES (valor1, valor2,...);
```